# Collectionview images overlay while scrolling and does not fit the screen

Tags: ios, swift5, collectionview

I am trying to learn collectionview by developing a gallery app. I am almost done with the app, but while scrolling the images, I could see the edge of the previous image as show in the screenshot.

- I have made the minimum spacing to 0.
- I have reload the collectionview.
- I have tried with Aspect fill, scall to fill

I am getting the error :

The item height must be less than the height of the UICollectionView minus the section insets top and bottom values, minus the content insets top and bottom values.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with keeping min-spacing for both cells and lines to zero? 
[image]
Also try to debug your view using View Debugger.
[image]

Comment: As i mentioned in my question  i have already tried that. But no use.

Comment: Did you find anything interesting using `View Debugger`?

Comment: I could not find anything with the View Debugger